# Windows IoT TcpClient

Tags: windowsiot, windows-iot-core-10

I want to send a command to my Sonos speaker. With my Windows application that is easy. I just use the TcpClient example provided on Microsoft website (shown below).

```
    public void Connect(String server, String message)
    {
        try
        {                
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, 1400);

            // Translate the passed message into ASCII and store it as a Byte array.
            Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

            // Get a client stream for reading and writing.
            //  Stream stream = client.GetStream();

            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

            // Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

            //Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", message);

            // Receive the TcpServer.response.

            // Buffer to store the response bytes.
            data = new Byte[256];

            // String to store the response ASCII representation.
            String responseData = String.Empty;

            // Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
            Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
            //Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", responseData);

            // Close everything.
            stream.Close();
            client.Close();
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException e)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException: {0}", e);
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
          //  Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
        }

        //Console.WriteLine("\n Press Enter to continue...");
        //Console.Read();
    }
```

Now, how would I go about doing this with Windows 10 IoT on a Raspberry Pi 3?

Answer (score 0):

With UWP, you may need to reference the "System.Net.Sockets" Nuget package in order to use TcpClient. You probably end up with something like below snippet,

```
    async void FunctionName()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var client = new TcpClient())
            {
                await client.ConnectAsync(server, 1400);

                // Translate the passed message into ASCII and store it as a Byte array.
                Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

                // Get a client stream for reading and writing.
                //  Stream stream = client.GetStream();
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                // Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

                //Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", message);

                // Receive the TcpServer.response.

                // Buffer to store the response bytes.
                data = new Byte[256];

                // String to store the response ASCII representation.
                String responseData = String.Empty;

                // Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
                Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
                //Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", responseData);
            }
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException e)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException: {0}", e);
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            //  Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
        }

        //Console.WriteLine("\n Press Enter to continue...");
        //Console.Read();
    }
```

Note that you need to declare the Internet client capability in your project manifest file.

[image]
PS: There's also an alternative an alternative called [StreamSocket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocket.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Refer to an complete code sample from Microsoft github [repository](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/StreamSocket).

Also, if you're new to UWP programming, you should get yourself familar with the async/await pattern.